# transpose of System of equations

Tags: homogeneous-equation

Let $A$ be an $m\times n$ matrix of rank $n$ with real entries. Choose the correct statements.
1. $Ax=b$ has a solution for any $b$.
2. $Ax=0$ does not have a solution.
3. If $Ax=b$ has a solution, then it is unique.
4. $y'A=0$ for some non zero $y$, where $y'$ denotes the transpose vector of $y$.

Option 1 and 2 are false for sure. Option 3 is correct.
Any one kindly explain option 4.

Answer (score 0):

Option 4 could be false. Take $m = n = 2$ and let $A$ be the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix. Then $\mathbf y' = \mathbf 0'$ so that $\mathbf y = \mathbf 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If you transpose both sides you get:
$$
y' A = 0 \iff (y' A)' = 0' \iff 0 = A' y'' = A' y
$$
so 4. will not hold in general. ($m = n$, $A'$ invertible)